# Removing/Defining the language-identification Tag Wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic-questions

Since Language Identification is now officially off-topic here, 6 of the tagged questions are closed and 10 other are blatantly off-topic:

a) Should we remove the tag altogether.

b) Can someone define the tag clearly or can we discuss make a good and clear tag wiki?

[(b) was added after this answer](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1766/14731)

Comment: What do you mean? Tags can't be "closed".

Comment: @curiousdannii Updated

Comment: I have added a short description that is (hopefully) clear about off-topic-questions.

Comment: but @jknappen my question is about the tag, about should we remove it or define it?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak: I think that part of the question is already answered by bytebuster—the tag is here to stay.

Comment: ok @jknappen can you put the status-completed tag to this question now?

Comment: @WiccanKarnak: No I can't, this can only a diamond moderator do.

Comment: oh ok I think @prash can do this then? (was that a partial Yoda-speak there? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are not-(yet)-deleted questions, removing a tag may leave these Q's untagged at all.

Also, language-identification can (in theory) be a part of a bigger question, but not a single purpose of the OP.

What about stating this clearly within the **Tag Wiki**? This may prevent the users from asking potentially bad questions.

Comment: Updated the question :)

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that (your argument can be argued) , I am really sorry , I pressed on _rollback_ twice (and an _ok_ on the following dialog box) but it doesn't seem to revert, can you maybe rollback it?

Comment: I just updated the question, I think it pretty much covers what you said.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak, now it looks great; then please also unmark my answer as accepted, because now it only partially addresses the question (I provide with no text for Tag Wiki, maybe someone else could).

Comment: oh yeah that makes complete sense (:

Comment: Hello dear, use a answer to protect question is funny such as push _flag_ button.